# Racket - How to look a specific of a list of lists. (Finding average)

Tags: racket

Let's say we have a list of structures and we have a list than contains a list of these structures. How can I look a specific list?

Comment: You're probably getting down-votes and close-votes because it's difficult to understand what you're asking. Can you edit the question? Provide some code showing an example of the structures and lists you have in mind? Show code for what you've tried so far, that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list-ref](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) to access a determined element in a list.